# Correlated queries - In derived tables, can I have many nesting levels?

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, correlated-subquery, derived-table

The main question and the question itself is: ***In derived tables, can I have many nesting levels?***

Context:

I know that in MySQL you can't have correlated subqueries with two levels deep, but, using derived tables it seems that you can, **is this normal or is there something I don't know**, or
**does this 2 level thing only and STRICTLY affect correlated subqueries**?

```
SELECT table3.field1, table3.field2, (SELECT table1.field1 FROM table1 WHERE table1.a = table3.field2) AS calculated,
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE table2.c = table3.field2) AS derived) AS calculated2
FROM table3;
```

Comment: It's good programming practice to _qualify all columns_, at least when several tables/instances are involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL's limit on levels of nesting subqueries is 63, the same as the number of tables joined.

https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/8.0/sql/sql_lex.cc#L85

```
static constexpr const int MAX_SELECT_NESTING{sizeof(nesting_map) * 8 - 1};
```

`nesting_map` is a type defined as `uint64_t` a 64-bit integer. Therefore `sizeof(nesting_map)` is 8 bytes, and `MAX_SELECT_NESTING` works out to 64-1.

If you do exceed that number of levels of nesting subqueries, you get this error:

> ERROR 1473 (HY000): Too high level of nesting for select

Comment: Hi @Bill Karwin, great info, I was unaware of this data, but then why does the second query not find the reference of vidios.video_id if only 2 nesting levels?

Comment: Does `videos` have a column `video_id`? It seems like it has a column `videos.id` based on your condition joining to `comentarios`.

Comment: Yes of course @Bill Karwin, that's my mistake, I didn't realize it, but here in StackOverFlow I read that "Oracle does not correlate nested subqueries more than one level deep (and neither does MySQL)."

Comment: "Many databases will still recognize c, even when nested multiple levels. However, MySQL (and Oracle and I think MS Access) is a database that limits correlation clauses to one level deep" I read this here in another question

Comment: I don't think that's true. I tested your query after correcting it to `vidios.id` and it does not return an error.

Comment: Yes, me too thank you very much, now I have demystified that statement, one last question, is a derived table a kind of subquery? I will mark this answer as the best one.

Comment: Yes, refer to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html where they describe it as a type of subquery.

Comment: Great, thanks so much for everything @Bill Karwin. Ready marked as best answer